# What should I do, if anything, to make this question more focused?

Tags: discussion, questions, editing, closed-questions

I am rather confused as to why [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/256175/how-can-i-visualize-a-pde-boundary-condition) was closed.  It seems to me at least to be very easy to understand, and in fact I received the type of answer I was expecting.

My first thought was that perhaps one or two people simply saw that I had enumerated two parts to the question, and voted to close without reading the question itself (the two parts are very much related, essentially "1)  Is this the right geometry to draw for my problem, and 2) If so, how can I draw it?"), but then I saw that five people must have voted to close, unless one of them was a moderator, and it would be unlikely that all of them had made the same mistake.

I have read the description of a question that lacks focus, but it is hard for me to see how this question fits the bill or how to edit it so that it becomes more focused.

Comment: Yes, five people voted to close, not me, but I agree at least that your question is not what most people expect from a "good question". We don't see any of your efforts in Mathematica code, nor reference to any search in the documentation, no reasonable starting point. Just give me the answer, to a question that seems to be more about the Mathematical concept than about programming.

Comment: What you can do in the future is to show due diligence, explain how much you already know, show your failed attempts in actual well formatted code, try to make it easier to answer, keep the core of the question on-topic.

Comment: I agree with @rhermans. I would add it's not clear whether $\theta$ is to be treated as a polar or rectangular coordinate or what the second coordinate should be. (Questions should be self-contained, and this is easy information to include.) Also people like to have mathematical equations both in TeX and in code, but especially in code. Code shows what the OP is actually doing instead just what they think they're doing. Finally, you showed a Desmos graph, not a Mathematica one. It emphasizes you're asking a question that is basically just math, if you don't care which system renders your graph